# Обьясните как работает @wraps(func) детально пжл

Tags: python

Знаю что @wraps(func) снимает something() из inner функции но подскажите принцип работы пжл шаг за шагом

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import math 
import time
from functools import wraps

def decorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def inner(*args):
        start = timer()
        print(f"Function {func.__name__} starts its work")
        func(*args)
        end = timer()
        print(f"Function {func.__name__} took {end-start} time")

    return inner


@decorator
def something(a,b):
    time.sleep(3)
    print(a+b)
something(4,5)
#print(help(something))
```

Comment: Что значит "снимает"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Любой декоратор вида

```
def decor(): ...

@decor
def func(): ...
```

можно переписать так:

```
def decor(): ...

def func(): ...

func = decor(func)
```

В вашем случае,

```
@wraps(func)
def inner(): ...
```

То же, что и

```
def inner(): ...

inner = wraps(func)(inner)
# вызов wraps(func) возвращает другую функцию,
# которая сама выступает в роли декоратора, сразу же вызывается с аргументом (inner)
```

`wraps` пытается сделать обертку `inner` максимально похожей на исходную `func`

1. Берет значения атрибутов `('__module__', '__name__', '__qualname__', '__doc__', '__annotations__')` у функции `func` и присваивает их функции `inner`
2. Все значения из `func.__dict__` переносит в `inner.__dict__`. (Справка: `__dict__` — словарь, хранящий все атрибуты объекта. В случае любого присваивания атрибута а-ля `func.x = 0`, он сохраняется в словаре `func.__dict__['x']`)
3. Сохраняет ссылку на исходную функцию `inner.__wrapped__ = func`

---

Но просили пошагово - будет пошагово xD

Возможно, для начала стоит переписать `@`декораторы в виде обычного присваивания, для наглядности. Этот код делает то же самое, что и ваш:

**#1**

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import time
from functools import wraps

def decorator(func):
    # @wraps(func)
    def inner(*args):
        start = timer()
        print(f"Function {func.__name__} starts its work")
        func(*args)
        end = timer()
        print(f"Function {func.__name__} took {end-start} time")

    wrap = wraps(func)     # (*1)
    inner = wrap(inner)    # partial.__call__(wrap, inner)
                           # Пока не обращайте внимания.

    print(wrap.__class__)  # (!) <class 'functools.partial'>

    return inner

# @decorator
def something(a, b):
    time.sleep(3)
    print(a + b)

something = decorator(something) # ◄

something(4, 5)
```

Полез в исходный код `functools` (во всех кодах ниже, часть проверок и комментариев вырезаны), который и у вас должен лежать где-то тут:

`C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\functools.py`

Раз уж сперва вызывается `wraps(func)`, посмотрим, что он из себя представляет:

```
WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS = ('__module__', '__name__', '__qualname__', '__doc__',
                       '__annotations__')
WRAPPER_UPDATES = ('__dict__',)

def wraps(wrapped,
          assigned = WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS,
          updated = WRAPPER_UPDATES):

    """Decorator factory to apply update_wrapper() to a wrapper function"""

    return partial(update_wrapper, wrapped=wrapped,
                   assigned=assigned, updated=updated)
```

Т.е. у нас функция `func`, он же, `something` идет сюда в виде параметра `wrapped`

`update_wrapper` — какая-то вспомогательная функция, передается в виде аргумента.

Часть кода `partial`:

```
class partial:
    """New function with partial application of the given arguments and keywords"""

    __slots__ = "func", "args", "keywords", "__dict__", "__weakref__"

    def __new__(cls, func, /, *args, **keywords):
        self = super(partial, cls).__new__(cls)

        self.func = func
        self.args = args
        self.keywords = keywords
        return self

    def __call__(self, /, *args, **keywords):
        keywords = {**self.keywords, **keywords}
        return self.func(*self.args, *args, **keywords)
```

Справка: [object.__new__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__new__#object.__new__)

При вызове `partial(update_wrapper, wrapped=wrapped, assigned=assigned, updated=updated)` сперва вызывается его `__new__`. Где `cls` - это сам `partial`, а `func` - функция `update_wrapper`. Тут не происходит ничего особенного, всего лишь сохраняет ссылку на `update_wrapper` в атрибуте `.func`, а `wrapped, assigned, updated` - в виде словаря `.keywords`. А `self.args` в данном случае остается **п**устым.

---

На минуточку вернемся к блоку кода `#1`, в строчке `(*1)` если `wrap` — это экземпляр класса `partial`, получается, при вызове `inner = wrap(inner)` будет вызван метод `__call__` (он вызывается всякий раз, когда экземпляр класса пытаются вызвать как функцию)

`partial.__call__(wrap, inner)` // `wrap → self, inner → попадает в *args`

`__call__` в свою очередь вызывает `self.func` (это `update_wrapper`).

Получается вызов `update_wrapper(*self.args, *args, **keywords)` где:

• `*self.args` **п**устой

• `*args` содержит одну функцию `inner`

• `keywords` - ранее сохраненные `wrapped, assigned, updated`

`update_wrapper(inner, wrapped=wrapped, assigned=assigned, updated=updated)` — в итоге имеем такой вызов, где wrapped - ссылка на исходную функцию `something`

---

А что с `update_wrapper` ?

```
def update_wrapper(wrapper,   # inner
                   wrapped,   # something
                   assigned = WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS,
                   updated = WRAPPER_UPDATES):

    """Update a wrapper function to look like the wrapped function"""

    for attr in assigned:
        # assigned = ('__module__', '__name__', '__qualname__', '__doc__', '__annotations__')
        try:
            value = getattr(wrapped, attr)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        else:
            setattr(wrapper, attr, value)

    for attr in updated:
        # updated = ('__dict__',)
        getattr(wrapper, attr).update(getattr(wrapped, attr, {}))

    wrapper.__wrapped__ = wrapped
    return wrapper
```

Берет все необходимые атрибуты у `something` и присваивает их функции `inner`, сохраняет ссылку на исходную функцию в атрибуте `__wrapped__`

Comment: Я просто в шоке, лучше знать что @wraps работает как wraps) спасибо вам